# Office 365 Management API for UserLoggedIn notification

Tags: office365

After reading [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office-365-management-api/office-365-management-activity-api-schema#azure-active-directory-account-logon-schema), I know the AzureActiveDirectoryEventType-AccountLogon is represent a account login event, So I subscribe a webhook by using office 365 management API for receiving login data.

After a user login, I got a lots of notification data that operation is UserLoggedIn and the AzureActiveDirectoryEventType is AzureApplicationAuditEvent. But there is no AccountLogon event received from webhook.

So, dose UserLoggedIn use for tracking user's login activity? or does there have any other operation represent user's login activity?

Answer (score 0):

AzureActiveDirectoryEventType is The type of Azure AD event.

You can't query the Management Activity API for a particular event ID or RecordType or other properties in the content blob.

For this question, you can review the following link for reference:

[Troubleshooting the Office 365 Management Activity API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office-365-management-api/troubleshooting-the-office-365-management-activity-api)

To track user's activity, you can use sign-in activity reports in the Azure Active Directory portal.

For more information, please review the following link:

[Sign-in activity reports in the Azure Active Directory portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/reports-monitoring/concept-sign-ins)